# Execute Javascript after Rendering HandleBars Template Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, express-handlebars

i have a node application and i am trying to render a jquery datatable after the data has loaded,
so far i have been able to populate the table with the data but i am trying to initialize the datatable and its not working..

here i rander the template

```
router.get('/user/operations', (req, res)=>{
    var data;

    const data = axios.get('http://localhost:8945/api/users/operations')
    .then(function (response) {
       data = response.operations;  //i retrieve the data from the api
     })
    .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
    
    res.render('pages/tables', {
        pgtitle:'All User Operations..',
        usrData:data            // i pass the data to the template and successfully render the table
    });          
})
```

i rendered the view properly using HandleBars Template Engine, but the datatable doesn't initialize after the view has been rendered, the table has an id of `UsersDataTB` but if it was in jquery, i would have called the script below immediate after the rendering process to initialize the datatable.

```
 $('#UsersDataTB').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    pagingType: "full_numbers"
 });
```

but now i don't know where to run a script after the view-template has been rendered using HandleBars in Express, please how do i go about it,

Asides this, every other feature is working as expected.

Comment: Are you including the `DataTable` script in your template? Because that script should run in the frontend like you would do with a static HTML file.

Comment: yes i am,  but it has to be initialized, is there a way to run it without initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your express code I would think that the view will be rendered first before your `axios` request has finished. That is because of the asynchronous nature of the request Axios makes.

To make sure that you render your template **after** the data has been fetched use `async / await` or render your template in the `.then()` callback after the request has been made.

```
router.get('/user/operations', async (req, res) => {

  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8945/api/users/operations');
  const { operations } = response;

  res.render('pages/tables', {
    pgtitle: 'All User Operations..',
    usrData: operations
  }
       
})
```

If the `'pages/tables'` template contains a script with jQuery, the DataTable plugin and your initialization code then that script should run whenever the page has been loaded.

So if your script contains:

```
$('#UsersDataTB').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  pagingType: "full_numbers"
});
```

Then it should look for the `id="UsersDataTB"` element and create the data table. This **is** initializing the table. But I assume that your table is empty because there is no data.

Otherwise check your console for any error messages and inspect the data table element to see if there are any signs that the initialization went wrong.

---

### Edit

In your Handlebars template make sure that your `usrData` is an array with object that can be looped over to make sure that your template renders a table with multiple rows and cells. And then initialize it with the script after it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <table id="UsersDataTB">
      <tbody>
        {{#each usrData}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{@key}}</td>
            <td>{{this}}</td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#UsersDataTB').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i actually did all of this, and you're right about the axios - i have to render the template after the data has been made available. i have taken care of that already.

Comment: But, then, i tried to create a datatable directly on the view with static content. because thats what i normally do, i start with static content to give me an overview of what i should be expecting, then i stretch it with dynamic content. now the issue is - the static table did not render.. i just rendered it like every other jquery datatable but i realized that you cant run javascript directly inside handlebars template engine, there has to be something extra that is being done.. i've gone all over the internet looking for that solution but to no avail.

Comment: if you can render a datatable using Handlebars template engine, or if you know any tutorial reference that i can follow.. please help me out. i've also gone over youtube but i'm still yet to find any. thanks.

Comment: You can't render the data table in Handlebars. That is because it is not yet HTML. To handlebars your templates are just strings which are built and served by the server. It can only be rendered by the client, because the data table plugin runs on jQuery, a frontend JavaScript library.

Comment: @Zuurbiel please what alternative do i have... i'd really appreciate, do you have any suggestions. what template engine can i use to achieve this.

Comment: It might help if you include your Handlebars template. And make sure the jQuery,  DataTable and your own scripts are included there as well. But as alternatives go, there are none, because you're trying to do frontend work on the server. You can't add interactivity on the server, that is what the client is for. I've added an example for a handlebars template which you should check out and see if your own template follows the same structure.